# Происхождение слова "акула"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке появлось слово "акула"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько версий. По самой распространенной - это слово поморского, карельского или даже исландского происхождения. Но также в русском языке было слово "окула", означающее "плут", "обманщик".